# Как добавить в Trello ссылку сайта

Tags: javascript, trello

Нужно добавить в Trello закладку сайта на котором сейчас нахожусь.
Есть для этого официальный инструмент [trello.com/add-card](https://trello.com/add-card),  который с помощью закладки добавляет в трелло карточку с заголовком текущей страницы, ссылку и картинку.

Не устраивает, потому что ссылку добавляет в прикрепленные файлы, а нужна она в описании карточки. Так же напрягает, что в Safari, при закрытии окна просит подтверждение.

Как создать такую закладку, чтобы добавляла сайт в описание карточки, заголовок в название, картинку в прикрепленные файлы и выделеный текст на странице в описание?

Либо же - как изменить официальный код, чтобы добавлялась ссылка в описание?

```
javascript:(function(win%2Cname%2Cdesc)%7Bwin.open('https%3A%2F%2Ftrello.com%2Fadd-card'%2B'%3Fsource%3D'%2Bwin.location.host%2B'%26mode%3Dpopup'%2B'%26url%3D'%2BencodeURIComponent(win.location.href)%2B(name%3F'%26name%3D'%2BencodeURIComponent(name)%3A'')%2B(desc%3F'%26desc%3D'%2BencodeURIComponent(desc)%3A'')%2C'add-trello-card'%2C'width%3D500%2Cheight%3D600%2Cleft%3D'%2B(win.screenX%2B(win.outerWidth-500)%2F2)%2B'%2Ctop%3D'%2B(win.screenY%2B(win.outerHeight-740)%2F2))%7D)(window%2Cdocument.title%2CgetSelection%3FgetSelection().toString()%3A'')
```

Зараннее спасибо!